# Opengl debugging, how to see results of vertex shader

Tags: debugging, opengl

Is there a way to see the final position (and other attributes) of a vertex after the vertex shader has processed it, without relying on further rendering?  Being able to see the input -> output of my vertex shader stage alone by itself would be a huge boon to help with debugging.

I use Visual Studio 2015, if it has such a debugging utility available (I also use Nsight, but cannot find anything along these lines there)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Renderdoc](https://renderdoc.org/) has such feature.

'Pipeline State' -> 'Vertex Input' -> 'Mesh View' opens a window that lists vertex shader inputs and outputs:

[image: pic]

<sup>(Screenshot is from Renderdoc manual.)</sup>